# how can I build Tensorflow c++ API with my project on linux?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I've been developing a C++ project using Tensorflow. The project can build normally, but it just using CPU.

I execute configure file in Tensorflow (check enable GPU) and I tried to build it with **--config=cuda** option, but it was failed with this error.

(label_image in tensorflow example build with GPU as well )

```
$$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //engine:main

ERROR: /home/User/.cache/bazel/_bazel_User/aa58bdbbe2038eb91c944f024098159f/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD:4:1: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/User/.cache/bazel/_bazel_User/aa58bdbbe2038eb91c944f024098159f/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD", line 4
            error_gpu_disabled()
    File "/home/User/.cache/bazel/_bazel_User/aa58bdbbe2038eb91c944f024098159f/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/error_gpu_disabled.bzl", line 3, in error_gpu_disabled
            fail("ERROR: Building with --config=c...")
ERROR: Building with --config=cuda but TensorFlow is not configured to build  with GPU support. Please re-run ./configure and enter 'Y' at the prompt to build with GPU support.
ERROR: no such target '@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain': target 'toolchain' not declared in package 'crosstool' defined by /home/wklee/.cache/bazel/_bazel_User/aa58bdbbe2038eb91c944f024098159f/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD.
```

My project tree

```
|-- WORKSPACE
|-- configure
|-- engine
|   |-- BUILD
|   `-- main.cc
|-- models
|-- tensorflow
|-- tools
|   `-- bazel.rc
```

WORKSPACE::

```
workspace(name = "Project")

local_repository(
    name="tensorflow",
    path="/home/User/project/tensorflow/"
)
load("@tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace.bzl", "tf_workspace")
tf_workspace(path_prefix="/home/User/project/tensorflow/",tf_repo_name="@tensorflow")
```

I'm not familiar with bazel and don't quite understand **bazel.rc** file in tools. It just copy from tensorflow directory

Comment: did you:" re-run ./configure and enter 'Y' at the prompt to build with GPU support."

Comment: Could you include the output of ./configure in your post?